# Averaging neighbors' variables to inform decision

Tags: netlogo

The proejct I'm building is a little too big to post here; I think this snippet should suffice.

```
breed [CMs CM]

CMs-own [flag?]

to go

set flag? random 2
check-von-neumann-neighborhood

end

to check-von-neumann-neighborhood

 create-links-with CMs-on neighbors4

 ifelse mean flag? of CMs-on neighbors4 >= 0.5
 [set flag? 1]
 [set flag? 0]

end
```

What I'm trying (and failing) to do here is to ask each CM to average the values of "flag?" of its Von Neumann neighbors and then take on that value as its own flag?.

I slapped the create-link-with code on there because I thought it would allow CMs to sense its neighbor's flag?, but that doesn't appear to me the problem.

The error message highlights "flag?" in "ifelse mean flag? of CMs-on neighbors4 >= 0.5" and says "OF expected this input to be a reporter block, but got anything instead."

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the links, NetLogo can detect the turtles on the neighbouring patches and then access the variables of those turtles. Your problem is that you have `flag? of` but need `[flag?] of`.

The error message means that you have used `of` without telling NetLogo what to report. You need the [ ] to mark the boundary of the reporter block, even if it's simply a variable. Reporter blocks could be complicated calculations so NetLogo needs to know where to start and end the calculations for each entity that is reporting (in this case, all the CMs on the `neighbors4`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked partially. Now the list of values [flag?] of neighbor turtles is always empty for the second turtle who’s doing this mean operation. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: No idea. Your snippet doesn't actually have any of the `ask` elements, so it's impossible to tell. Ask a new question with the relevant code and description of the problem.